# How long would it take a 400 W solar panel to charge a 28 kWh EV battery?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charging, panel, electric-vehicle

I'm located in The Gambia which is almost on the equator. We get over 11 hours of sunlight on Dec. 21st. Being a tiny country, daily travel is minimal, at most, maybe 28 km. If I place a 400 watt panel on top of an EV with a 28 kWh battery and a range of 300 km, I'm assuming I'd be close to never having to plug it in. Does my assumption seem reasonable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

28000/400: at least 70 hours of 100% sun, which in the real world is 10-20 days on average, plus whatever efficiency losses your solar controller/charging circuitry introduce, let's call it 90% efficient so maybe 11-22 days.

Edit: also factor in the battery self discharge which might add a day or two.

Comment: And if your season is winter multiply by 5 or more.

Comment: I'd say self-discharge shouldn't be an issue here. But the losses during DC/DC conversion may be much worse than 10%. Solar Panels are ususally 12-24V output. EV batteries require 400-800V.

Comment: I'm located in The Gambia which is almost on the equator. We get over 11 hours of sunlight on Dec. 21st.. Being a tiny country, daily travel is minimal, at most, maybe 28km. If I place a 400 watt panel on top of an EV with a 28kwh battery and a range of 300km, I'm assuming I'd be close to never having to plug it in. Does my assumption seem reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

Where I am, the Netherlands, it will take at least two months now.

In November an [ideally placed](https://www.thomasberger.be/pv/pvcalc/index.html?date=20231128&long=4.385&lat=51.134&az=180&roof=45&peakw=400&temp_coeff=-0.48&max=5000&az2=0&roof2=0&peakw2=0&temp_coeff2=0&max2=0) 400 Wp panel produces 18 kWh, and December 13 kWh.

In May you get two charges a month.